# How I do start my laptop without power button

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, power-management

I have an old **HP pavilion g6 1095st**. Now I've organized a new desk design and i would like to use this laptop external monitor and only mouse and keyboard on the desk. Here is the problem. In the BIOS there is no *Keyboard Wake On* settings to switch enabled. (BIOS version is insydeh20).

Is there anyway to start the laptop with any external usb solution or something else?

Ps: In Device Management all power box are checked.

Comment: Creative use of the tag [power-management]. Also not quite sure why it is tagged [keyboard] since you already mentioned that the keyboard would be useless. Having said all that, why not use two long cables, a button and connect those to the laptops power switch? Short of a docking station (with its own power plug) that might work best.

Comment: How about Wake-on-LAN? Your computer is more likely to support that than wake on keyboard, and you can use an app from your phone to turn it on that way.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  Trying to do the same thing with a physical button & not cracking open the Case.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to configure Wake on LAN (WOL) for the computer so that it can be turned on remotely. This way you don't need a physical button to press.

There are a few options for doing this but one of the easiest would be to use TeamViewer as you can wake the computer from your iOS/Android device.

Reference from TeamViewer website: [How does Wake-on-LAN with TeamViewer work?](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-does-Wake-on-LAN-with-TeamViewer-work/ta-p/33)

Comment: Of course sounds like cool option. But there is a couple problem with that. 
If someone else have to use computer, what will do in this situation or sth else. 
 I do not depend on any other device or something to my pc

Answer (score 0):

Low-tech answer... If you're willing to take apart the old laptop a little bit, you can extract the power button.  Note which leads go into which ..  Get a long paired wire leading out to the desktop, solder the appropriate leads, and see if it will start.  Of course, this sort of hack may break it, so consider other options first.

Comment: yes this is the one option that in my mind. Also most primitive as well